# How to compare results from sub query in main query

Tags: sql, teradata, teradatasql

I want to compare results from subquery with the column in main query

```
--this returns multiple rows 
select id, MAX(created_date) as maxdate from table 
group by id
```

I want to use the result set in the another query to compare date (already exist in the table) with created_date for matching id, since sub query is return multiple rows unable to use it in a sub query I get the following error `More than one value was returned by a subquery.`.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Basic SQL question? Use JOIN or IN or EXISTS not =

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
select t1.id, t1.created_date, t2.maxdate 
from table1 as t1
join (
  select id, MAX(created_date) as maxdate from table1 
  group by id
) as t2 on 
t1.id = t2.id
```